# Halmos's minimality condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm working on the last bit of Halmos' Families exercises, page 37 in *Naive Set Theory*. He states that we have $J \subset I$ and a nonempty family $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$, which gives rise to $\bigcap_{i} X_i \subset X_j \subset \bigcup_{i} X_i$ (with $i \in I, j \in J$).

It then goes on to say that if $X_j \subset Y$ for all $j$ then $\bigcup_{i} X_i \subset Y$.

$Y$ hasn't been otherwise described before that I see. So I'm not sure how we arrive at this implication. By hypothesis $Y$ can have members that are not in any $X_j$, but that doesn't imply that these members must be in some $X_i$.

Looking at other threads on this exercise on the internet, it looks like some people assume $\bigcup_i X_i \subset Y$. But I don't see in the book that this subset relationship is given.

Comment: Do you mean $i \in I$ and $j \in J$?

Comment: Yes, edited original post to add that

Comment: Maybe the author meant $X_i\subset Y$ for all $i\in I$? Otherewise the statement is just false.

Comment: I checked on [Halmos's book](https://piazza.com/class_profile/get_resource/ixbzgb46cf85ri/iyk9bc6qqhx7do): he never says that $J\subseteq I$. Actually, there is only a set of index $I$.

Comment: After checking Halmo's book I vote to close the question because then I think it's not clear what the OP is asking.

Comment: In the previous paragraph he says $J \subset I$. I take it the exercise continues that assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Halmos's book](https://piazza.com/class_profile/get_resource/ixbzgb46cf85ri/iyk9bc6qqhx7do) (p. 37), there are three things to prove (assume $I \neq \emptyset$; note that your reading of the exercise is wrong, there is only one index set $I$):

1. $\bigcap_{i \in I} X_i \subseteq X_j \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i$ for all $j \in I$;
2. minimality of $\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i$: if $X_j \subseteq Y$ for all $j \in I$ then $\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \subseteq Y$;
3. maximality of $\bigcap_{i \in I} X_i$: if $Y \subseteq X_j$ for all $j \in I$ then $Y \subseteq \bigcap_{i \in I} X_i$.

*Proof.*

1. Let $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} X_i$: then $x \in X_j$ for all $j \in I$; therefore, $\bigcap_{i \in I} X_i \subseteq X_j$ for all $j \in I$. 
   Let $j \in I$ and $x \in X_j$: then $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i$; therefore $X_j \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i$ for all $j \in I$.
2. Assume $Y$ is such that $X_j \subseteq Y$ for all $j \in I$. Let $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i$. Then $x \in X_{j_0}$ for some $j_0 \in I$, and hence $x \in Y$ (since $X_{j_0} \subseteq Y$). Therefore, $\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \subseteq Y$.
3. Assume $Y$ is such that $Y \subseteq X_j$ for all $j \in I$. Let $x \in Y$. Then $x \in X_{j}$ for all $j \in I$, and hence $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} X_i$. Therefore, $Y \subseteq \bigcap_{i \in I} X_i$.

Comment: I see, so the way you read it is $j$ is just another name for a member of $I$? I was carrying forward the $J \subset I$ assumption from page 36.

Comment: @Benjamin - Yes, $j$ is just another name for a member of $I$.

Comment: In number 3 of exercise statement, the last union must be an intersection. Please correct it.

Comment: @OmidSadeghi - Sure, it's a typo. I fixed it. Well spotted, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without the assumption $X_i\subseteq Y$ for all $i\in I$, this is false: take $X_0=\{0\}$, $X_1=\{1\}$, and $Y=X_0$ with $J=\{0\}\subseteq \{0,1\}=I$.  Clearly $X_j\subseteq Y$ for all $j\in J$, but $$\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i=X_0\cup X_1=\{0,1\}\not\subseteq \{0\}=Y\text{.}$$

But assuming $X_i\subseteq Y$ for each $i\in I$ (which is probably how the question should be read), we can show $\bigcup_i X_i\subseteq Y$ pretty directly.  Suppose $x\in \bigcup_i X_i$.  Thus there is some $i'\in I$ with $x\in X_{i'}$.  Since $X_{i'}\subseteq Y$, it follows that $x\in Y$.  This means that $x\in\bigcup_{i}X_i$ implies $x\in Y$, and thus $\bigcup_{i}X_i\subseteq Y$.